# Chat between specific users using SignalR and Angular client

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, signalr

I'm trying to make a chat between two clients that you can choose from the connected clients list. So far everything is working good - I have the list and I succeeded to send messages to all clients by using `Clients.All.SendAsync`.

The problem starts when I'm trying to use

```
Clients.Client(connectionId).
```

In my client side (Angular), where I'm displaying the connected clients list, I've added a button to each client so you can send him a message:

[image]

I have click event to send the connectionId to the server, so it will know who to send a message to. I debugged the program and saw that I'm reaching to the server with the right data (the connectionId to send him a message) and when I'm getting back to the client no message is printed. Also I'm not getting any error on the console. What am I doing wrong?

Server side:

Controller-

```
 [HttpPost("SendMessageToUser")]
    public Task<IActionResult> SendMessageToUser([FromBody] ChatMessageDto chatMessageDto)
    {
        IActionResult actionResult;
        if (chatMessageDto.Validate())
        {
            Response response=_signalrService.SendMessageToUser(chatMessageDto.ConnectionId,chatMessageDto.Message);
            actionResult=Ok(response);
        }
        else
        {
            actionResult = BadRequest();
        }
        return Task.FromResult(actionResult);
    }
```

Service-

```
    public Response SendMessageToUser(string connectionId, string message)
    {
        Response response;

        UserHub hub = new UserHub(_userHubContext);
        hub.SendMessageToUser(message, connectionId);

        response = new Response
        {
            Message = message,
            IsSuccess = true
        };

        return response;
    }
```

Hub-

```
    public void  SendMessageToUser(string message, string connectionId)
    {
        _hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("GetMessage", message).Wait();
    }
```

Client side:

user.ts component - only partial code that relevant (there is continuance in my computer)

```
startSignalrConnection(): void {
this.signalRService
  .startSignalrConnection(this.signalrConnectionUrl)
  .then((signalrHubConnectionId) => {
    firstValueFrom(
      this.http.post(
        this.addClientUrl,
        //get user name from local storage
        buildNewChatClientConnectionModel(
          this.chatClientId,
          signalrHubConnectionId,
          this.userName!
        )
      )
    )
      .then((response) => {
        this.signalRService.addListenersMsg();
        // Add function call for getting all connected users
        this.userService.getConnectedUsers().subscribe((users) => {
          this.users = users;
        });
```

user.html component-

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
    <div class="users-list">
        <div><strong>Id: </strong>{{user?.chatClientId}}</div>
        <div><strong>ConnectionId: </strong>{{user?.connectionId}}</div>
        <div><strong>Name: </strong>{{user?.name}}</div>
        <button class="button" [disabled]="chatMessage.length==0" (click)="sendMessageToUser(user?.connectionId)">Send Message</button>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

sendMessageToUser (on the same component)-

```
sendMessageToUser(sendToConnId: any): void {
  this.sendToConnId=sendToConnId;
  this.signalRService.sendMessageToUser(
  this.sendMessageToUserUrl,
  this.chatMessage,
  this.sendToConnId,
   );
}
```

SignalR service-

```
public addListenersMsg() {
this.hubConnection.on("GetMessage", (message: string, connectionId: string) => {
  this.messages.push(buildDisplayChatMessageModel(new Date(), message));
});
}

public sendMessageToUser(sendMessageToUserUrl: string, message: string, sendToConnId: any){
firstValueFrom(this.http.post(sendMessageToUserUrl, buildChatMessageModel(sendToConnId, message)))
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Failed to send message: ", error);
    alert("Failed to send message: "+ error);
  })   
}
```